# Generating PDF on the fly with standard HTTP response fields

Tags: http, web

I'm developing a web page with a form which returns a PDF document based on the form data. Currently I use the HTTP response fields

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.pdf"
```

However, since the field *Content-Disposition* is non-standard and doesn't work in all browsers I'm looking for a different approach. Do I have to save the PDF document on the server? What is the modus operandi?

Edit: By "doesn't work in all browsers" I mean that with some browsers the filename is not set to *foo.pdf*. Dillo, for instance, just sets the default filename (in the download dialog) to the basename of the URL path (plus query string).

Comment: cut out the "attachment;". This forces the user to download it instead of viewing it. Everything else is pretty much standard and works in all browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Content-Disposition is non-standard and doesn't work in all browsers"_? What is "work?" What do you want to happen with the PDF? What do you think saving the document will solve?

Comment: @bytecode77 Content-Disposition is not part of the HTTP/1.1 standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266).

Comment: It is completely irrelevant if you save the document on the server or not. That makes absolutely no difference to the client.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I've never seen a browser that doesn't support that.

Comment: @CodeCaster In some lesser known browsers, like Dillo, the filename is not set correctly; instead of *foo.pdf* the suggested filename is the file plus the query string from the URL.

Comment: @arkascha But then I need to schedule some script which periodically deletes the PDF documents.

Comment: sorry, you did not really read my comment.

Comment: Content-Disposition is defined in RFC 6266 and is a "standard" just like the HTTP/1.1 base specs are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to save the PDF document on the server?

No. As far as the HTTP client is concerned it, the inner workings of the server are completely opaque to it. All it sees is a TCP stream of bytes from the server and how exactly that stream is produced doesn't matter as long as it matches the specified `Content-Type`.

Just send the PDF right after the HTTP headers and you're done with.

#### Update due to comment

So if you're wondering how to supply a filename without using a header field: Just augment the URL with it. I.e. something like

```
http://${DOMAIN}/${PDF_GENERATOR}/${DESIRED_FILENAME}
```

In the HTTP server add a rewrite rule to simply omit the filename part and redirect to just

```
http://${DOMAIN}/${PDF_GENERATOR}
```

The HTTP client does not see that, all it see is some URL ending with a "filename", that it can present the user as a default for saving.

Comment: Yes, but if a browser only accepts the fields in the HTTP/1.1 standard it will ignore the specified filename and instead use, for instance, the base name of the URL with the query string, which is not a good name for a PDF document.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Well, then simply make the last element of the URL a proper filename and let the CGI/PHP/whatever ignore it (or simply use a rewrite rule in the HTTP server). There's no law written, that URLs have to map to filenames whatsoever. Oh, and in case you wonder: The RFCs permit to have further path elements *after* GET variables. E.g. `http://example.com/pdfcreate.cgi?var=foo/document.pdf` is a perfectly valid URL. Of course one could use a POST method request for that either.